# Basic UIImageView mask shape with Bezier Paths

Tags: ios, swift, drawing

I want to make a profile photo look like this picture.
I am experimenting with UIBezierPaths() and I believe they are my best option.

[image]

I am also new to drawing in iOS but so far I've been able to achieve this shape:

[image]
For what I've been able to learn. Code :

```
extension UIImage {
    class func shapeImageWithBezierPath(bezierPath: UIBezierPath, fillColor: UIColor?, strokeColor: UIColor?, strokeWidth: CGFloat = 0.0) -> UIImage! {
        //: Normalize bezier path. We will apply a transform to our bezier path to ensure that it's placed at the coordinate axis. Then we can get its size.
        bezierPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -bezierPath.bounds.origin.x, y: -bezierPath.bounds.origin.y))
        let size = CGSize(width: bezierPath.bounds.size.width, height: bezierPath.bounds.size.height)

        //: Initialize an image context with our bezier path normalized shape and save current context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        context.saveGState()

        //: Set path
        context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)
        //: Set parameters and draw
        if strokeColor != nil {
            strokeColor!.setStroke()
            context.setLineWidth(strokeWidth)
        } else { UIColor.clear.setStroke() }
        fillColor?.setFill()
        context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)

        //: Get the image from the current image context
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        //: Restore context and close everything
        context.restoreGState()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        //: Return image
        return image
    }
}


  let circleShapePath = UIBezierPath()
circleShapePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 0))
circleShapePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
circleShapePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
circleShapePath.close()

let newCircle = UIImage.shapeImageWithBezierPath(bezierPath: cirleShapePath, fillColor: .red, strokeColor: .white, strokeWidth: 5)
```

My trouble has been finding the right way to connect the top left and bottom point with a curve line and mast it to a UIImageview.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this website to generate your desired shape, then copy the code (you might have to modify syntax based on your Swift version) to your project:
http://www.radicalphase.com/bezierpath/